# Is there a way to change private attribute of an Aspect progammatically?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-aspect

Say I have something like the following.

```
def _foo_aspect_impl(target, ctx):
    # operations

    return FooInfo(...)

foo_aspect = aspect(implementation = _foo_aspect_impl,
    attr_aspects = ['deps'],
    attrs = dict(
        _tool = attr.Label(
            # defs
        ),
    )
)

def _foo_rule_impl(ctx):
    for dep in ctx.attr.deps:
        # do something with `dep[FooInfo]`

    return DefaultInfo(...)

foo_rule = rule(
    implementation = _foo_rule_impl,
    attrs = dict(
        "deps": attr.label_list(
            aspects = [foo_aspect],
        )
    )
)
```

Is there a way to change the value of `foo_aspect.attr._tool`, either in `WORKSPACE`, or at the invocation of `foo_rule`?  Former is much preferable.

The use case being that version and repository origin of `_tool` might change from project to project.  When aspect resides in a repository shared by two projects, it does not make sense to create two branches for these two projects just for versioning of `_tool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching I found a rather complicated way of doing it.

Since the only thing that seems to be configuarable in `WORKSPACE.bazel` during loading phase is other workspaces / repositories, one could actually use target aliasing together with repository loading to mutiplex configuarable targets.

Here is how it works.

First, define a new repository rule `new_virtual_repository`, which creates repositories that does nothing but loading the `BUILD.bazel` and `WORKSPACE.bazel` files.

```
# repo.bzl

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:utils.bzl", "workspace_and_buildfile")

def _new_virtual_repo_impl(ctx):
    # Create build file
    workspace_and_buildfile(ctx)
    return ctx.attr

new_virtual_repository = repository_rule(
    implementation = _new_virtual_repo_impl,
    attrs = dict(
        build_file = attr.label(allow_single_file = True),
        build_file_content = attr.string(),
        workspace_file = attr.label(allow_single_file = True),
        workspace_file_content = attr.string(),
    ),
    local = True,
)
```

Then, create an extension file `config.bzl` which implements a function that generates the `BUILD.bazel` file and load the virtual repository:

```
# config.bzl

load(":repo.bzl", "new_virtual_repository")
def config(tool):
    build_file_content = """
alias(
    name = "tool",
    actual = "%s",
""" % (tool)

    new_virtual_repository(
        name = "config_repo",
        build_file_content = build_file_content,
    )
```

Now in the aspect specification:

```
# aspect.bzl

foo_aspect = aspect(
    ...
    attrs = dict(
        _tool = attr.Label("@config_repo//:tool"),
    )
)
```

Finally, configure the actual tool in `WORKSPACE.bazel`:

```
# WORKSPACE.bazel

load("//:config.bzl", "config")
config(tool="<actual_tool_label>")
```